# Start Verification Button not showing in FB business manager account

Tags: facebook, facebook-business-manager

1. Do anyone has idea Start Verification button not showing in my FB business manager account ?
2. What sort of things required to show this button?
3. How it will show in my account ??

I was following this blog https://www.businesschat.io/post/6-simple-steps-to-get-your-business-verified-on-facebook
[image]?

Answer (score 1):

**You have to create Simple App to enable the start verification process.**

Under Accounts, you can see Apps menu. In that apps home page, you need to create simple app id using Add menu button. Once you create this app then automatically Verification button will be enabled.

Comment: no help.. I already created 3 apps but still no start verification button visible on security center